# Wanting to use the substring method to remove characters from a string in a <p> element

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm sure this will be really simple to someone out there but i'm wanting to use js to remove the last 10 characters in a string (that's inside a p element). Can anybody help please!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ele = document.getElementById( 'myPId' );
ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.substring( 0, ele.innerHTML.length - 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `<p>` element only contains text:

```
<p id="test">Here is lots of nice text</p>
```

... the safest way is to alter the text node directly:

```
var textNode = document.getElementById("test").firstChild;
textNode.data = textNode.data.slice(0, -10);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply - I'm having an issue getting the code to work. I have replaced the "test" with the <p> id which is pubdate but nothing happens, although the js seems to be loading correctly. Any thoughts? Thanks :)

Comment: I have tested the code and it works, so without know your page I can't tell. Do you have a test page somewhere we can see?

Comment: Hi Tim, apologies - my mistake it's working perfectly. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If I wanted to do the same for multiple p elements with a class instead of using an ID could i use document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("class", "test"); ?